# Редактор с использованием html, css, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как реализовать редактор на html, css, javascript, в котором можно было бы:

1. местами выделять написанный текст жирным шрифтом или курсивом
2. отмечать перечисления точками (пунктами)
3. вставлять фрагменты кода (с подсветкой синтаксиса)  ?

```
<div> здесь фрагмент кода </div>
```

Может есть какие-то готовые решения (с примерами использования)? Потому что я создал `textarea`, начал гуглить и понял, что `textarea` для этого не подходит и что для такой реализации потребуется написать тонну js и css кода.

P.S. Что касается последнего пункта, я читал о `CodeMirror`, но не смог найти, как вставлять область для кода в нужное место и подогнать эту область под размер написанного там кода.

P.S.S Я пишу блог, и мне нужен этот редактор для создания и редактирования постов.

Comment: А воспользоваться любой готовой блог-платформой типа Вордпресс нельзя? Чтобы не изобретать велосипед...

Comment: @Инквизитор, нет, надо самому написать - такое задание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [ссылка](https://gist.github.com/monolithed/8e36983c02859b95dad7edc956d8b806)  смотрите и выбирайте то, что вам нужно..
Это готовые редакторы (jQuery плагины).
Вот ещё [ссылка](https://g.zeos.in/?q=jQuery%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9).